# Creating a namespaced resource from within a different namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I am creating a gallery application, and I want the ability to have public and private galleries. I have the public galleries set up pretty well, I think, but I'm having some trouble conceptualizing the private galleries. I'm considering the possibility of having a Private namespace with galleries and images, then assigning a user as the owner of a specific gallery so that they are the only ones who can access the gallery.

If I were to do something like that, would I be able to create a new private gallery from within the Admin Namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having separate namespaces, how about using something like CanCan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization?

You could have a boolean field of `private` do something like:

```
can :read, Gallery, :private => true, :user_id => user.id
```

So that a user can only view a private Gallery if he owns it.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that CanCan requires a user to be logged in to determine if a user "can" access a resource? When I say I want a public resource, what I mean is that I don't want a user to have to login to access it.

Comment: @YuKagi I believe if a user is not logged in, they are considered a guest. You could set an ability such as:

`can :read, Gallery, :private => false`

I believe then any user (even those not logged in) can view a Gallery that is not private. UPDATE: You might even be able to ignore the `:private => false` part since the other ability restricts the private Galleries.

Comment: Just watched the Railscast on CanCan, and it looks perfect. I haven't verified it yet, but it looks promising. Thank you very much for pointing me in this direction.